# Add combobox items from another usercontrol form using textbox

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I have a usercontrol form named "ucSETTINGS", where there is a textbox and once the button was clicked, the text inside the textbox will be added to the combobox from another usercontrol form name "ucITEMS"

I tried this code but it's not working
(cboCategory is the name of the combobox from ucITEMS, txtNAME is the textbox from ucSETTINGS)

```
Private Sub btnSAVE_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSAVE.Click
   Dim category As New ucITEMS()
   category.cboCATEGORY.Items.Add(txtNAME.Text)
End Sub
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Did you mean to create a new instance of ucITEMS? Or find the existing ucITEMS controls on your form and add the text to that?

Comment: I just want to add new items in the combobox in ucITEMS using textbox from another usercontrol . Do you have any idea how to do that?

Comment: You keep saying "usercontrol form". That doesn't really mean anything. Are you actually talking about two different user controls on the same form?

Comment: Wouldn't ucITEMS.cboCATEGORY.Items.Add(txtNAME.Text) do it?

Comment: Think about how other controls work. One control on a form doesn't modify other controls on that same form. The form does the modifying. One control will raise an event and expose data, the form handles the event and gets the data, then the form passes the data to the other control. That's what you should be doing. `ucSettings` should expose the data via a property and raise an event when save button is clicked. The form handles the event and gets the property value. The form then sets a property or calls a method in `ucItems` and the user control then does as appropriate with that data.

Comment: I tried ucITEMS.cboCATEGORY.Items.Add(txtNAME.Text) but its error since ucITEMS is from another form

Comment: @AndrewMortimer, if that code is in one UC then it has not knowledge of the other UC, as should be the case.

Comment: @John can you give me a sample code?

Comment: I'm working on it now.

Answer (score 2):

In this sort of situation, the user controls don't know about each other by default and it should stay that way. The source UC just exposes an interface and lets whomever is watching use that as it sees fit. That means raising an event when something happens and exposing required data via properties, e.g.

```vb
Public Class SourceControl

    Public ReadOnly Property TextBox1Text As String
        Get
            Return TextBox1.Text
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Event Button1Click As EventHandler

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OnButton1Click(EventArgs.Empty)
    End Sub

    Protected Overridable Sub OnButton1Click(e As EventArgs)
        RaiseEvent Button1Click(Me, e)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The `Text` of the `TextBox` is exposed via a property and, when the user clicks the `Button`, the UC raises an event.

The destination UC provides an interface for new items to be provided but it adds them to its own `ComboBox`, e.g.

```vb
Public Class DestinationControl

    Public Sub AddItemToComboBox1(item As Object)
        ComboBox1.Items.Add(item)
    End Sub

End Class
```

The form then plays go-between, handling the event, getting the property and calling the method:

```vb
Private Sub SourceControl1_Button1Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SourceControl1.Button1Click
    DestinationControl1.AddItemToComboBox1(SourceControl1.TextBox1Text)
End Sub
```

Obviously you would use something more specific and appropriate than my generic naming.